# VBA - resuming Select Case after calling another Select Case within a userform

Tags: vba, excel

The entire code that I'm using is very long, so I'm abbreviating the first sub just to save space. In this example, if "New York University," "NYU," or "New York Univ." is in column O, it shows a userform that has buttons containing another Select Case routine. But once it runs the Sub called from the frmNYU userform, it needs to continue running the cases in the first FillIn Sub.

```
Sub FillIn()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 84 To LastRow

        If Range("K" & i) Like "B*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "M*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "D*" Then
            Select Case Range("O" & i)

                Case "University of Florida"
                    Range("N" & i) = "0761"   
                Case "University of North Texas"
                    Range("N" & i) = "1612"
                Case "New York University", "NYU", "New York Univ."
                    frmNYU.Show

            End Select
        End If
End Sub
```

Here's the Sub for one of the buttons on the frmNYU userform.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo Terminate
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 84 To LastRow

        If Range("K" & i) Like "B*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "M*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "D*" Then
            Select Case Range("O" & i)

                Case "New York University", "NYU", "New York Univ."
                    Range("N" & i) = "1234"

            End Select
        End If

    Next i

Terminate:
    Unload Me
    End
End Sub
```

The problem is that once the Select Case is ran from within the userform, it doesn't resume running the original FillIn Sub. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "End" line before the "End Sub" line in the command button code. "End" causes all your code to stop running.

Comment: Well, I put the "End" there to keep it from looping. Without it there, I get the userform popping up for each match it finds in the original Sub.

Comment: Well, that is the reason it is not resuming the code in FillIn. The userform is popping up each time because that is the way your code is written. You are showing the userform within a For loop.

Comment: I understand that, but what change do I need to make that not happen? I've tried using `On Error Resume Next`, and that doesn't help.

Comment: @Robby `End` is a big red "destroy the whole entire execution context" button that puts the handbrakes on your macro and stops it right there - no code can run after an `End` statement.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I understand that now, thanks. I guess my problem now is keeping the userform from popping up in the loop.

Comment: That said then change End to Exit Sub

Comment: Just remove it, it's redundant if you're exiting the sub anyway

Comment: @Robby, I think you should re-engineer your code, since there's no sense in having the same `For i = 84 To LastRow` loop and `If Range("K" & i) Like "B*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "M*" Or Range("K" & i) Like "D*" Then` checking inside it twice (in the main code and in the called by it userform). If you give us the big picture we could help you with that

Comment: I added a couple more cases to the first sub. There literally hundreds more, but it gives you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: You could add a boolean in FillIn to keep track of whether the userform has been shown yet or not. Only show the userform if the boolean is false. Once it has been shown once, set the boolean to true. (I am assuming that your code inside the userform only needs to run once and that it takes care of all the instances between 84 and lastrow that it needs to).

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers The code does need to be run once, but it may be ran multiple times. Could I add a boolean that would keep the boolean as false only until it sub was finished? If so, how would I do that?